# Which constructor is called in STL container given default instantiation?

Tags: c++, stl

In ["STL Tutorial and Reference Guide, Second Edition"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/1823420), in Example 6.8, author *David Musser* gives the following example to demonstrate, "When creating *N* copies of the initial value, the vector constructor calls the copy constructor of the element type":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class U {
    public:
        unsigned long        id;
        unsigned long        generation;
        static unsigned long total_copies;
        /************************************************************************/
        U() :
            id{0},
            generation{0}
        {
        }
        U(unsigned long n) :
            id{n},
            generation{0} 
        {
        }
        U(const U& src) :
            id{src.id},
            generation{src.generation+1} 
        {
            ++total_copies;
        }
        
        // EQUALITY
        bool operator==(const U& src) { return id == src.id; }
        bool operator!=(const U& src) { return id != src.id; }
        
        // ASSIGMENT
        U& operator=(const U& src) 
        {
            id = src.id;
            generation = src.generation + 1;
            ++total_copies;
        }
};

bool operator==(const U& u1, const U& u2) 
{
    return u1.id == u2.id;
}
bool operator!=(const U& u1, const U& u2) 
{
    return u1.id != u2.id;
}

unsigned long U::total_copies {0};

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    vector<U> vector1, vector2(3);
    for (int i=0; i!=3; ++i)
        cout << "vector2[" << i << "].generation: "
             << vector2[i].generation << endl;
             
    cout << "Total copies: " << U::total_copies << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

According to him, `vector<U> vector2(3)`, should:

1. Call the `U` default CTOR
2. Then call the `U` Copy CTOR, using the result from #1, to populate the vector, 3x.

Therefore, he prints his results as follows:

```
vector2[0].generation: 1                                                                                                                
vector2[1].generation: 1                                                                                                                
vector2[2].generation: 1                                                                                                                
Total copies: 3
```

However, when I run the code, it shows that the default CTOR is called 3x and thus `generation == 0` and no copies were created. My results:

```
vector2[0].generation: 0                                                                                                                
vector2[1].generation: 0                                                                                                                
vector2[2].generation: 0                                                                                                                
Total copies: 0
```

I also tried this in which I pass `U` an argument, and that *does* call the copy CTOR every time. Is this compiler dependent? Why is there a difference and is this something that we should be cognizant of when initializing user-defined objects within a container?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector (number 3 and 4)

Comment: @chris - That aligns with what I am getting. How does the author arrive at having the copy CTOR called using the #4 CTOR?

Comment: I included #3 because one of those overloads has the same caller usage. It's not only #4 you need to look at.

Comment: @chris - the book is definitely dated (2001), which means that his code used following format: ```explicit vector( size_type count, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());``` I suppose this would 1st call default CTOR (``const T& value=T()``) and then copy remaining. Since 2011 though, the same call to CTOR simply calls default CTOR every time. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

@chris pointed me to the `std::vector` CTOR page at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). It appears that the reason the book's results were different than mine is that, the book being written in 2001, called the following CTOR (*until 2011*):

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Therefore, calling `vector<U> vector2(3)` will first call the default `U` CTOR and then copy each one. According to documentation, "Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value."
However, since 2011, the following CTOR is called:

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

which, according to the documentation there, "Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made."